# How to call CMake from a python script using the environment set up by vcvarsall.bat?

Tags: python, visual-studio, batch-file, cmake

I have a python script for a C++ project that uses CMake as the build system. I want to use the CMake Ninja generator instead of the Visual Studio generator. However, the Ninja generator expects the environment to be set up as performed by the `vcvarsall.bat` batch file provided with the Visual Studio installation.

It's easy if you do everything manually because you can just call the `vcvarsall.bat` file, get a command prompt with the correct environment set up and then you can fire the `cmake -G Ninja` command from there.

Things become more difficult when trying to use a python script that has not been started in such an environment. How do I call the `vcvarsall.bat` file programmatically from python, followed by a cmake call in that environment?

I assume that the only way is to just fire one subprocess from python. But I cannot come up with a parameter list that would do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm lucky enough to have found an answer to my own question.

Here is the right python call to be used:

```py
src_dir   = ... # set your source dir here
build_dir = ... # set your build dir here

# retrieve visual studio installation path using vswhere.
# See: https://github.com/Microsoft/vswhere
vswhere = os.path.join(os.environ['ProgramFiles(x86)'],
                       "Microsoft Visual Studio",
                       "Installer",
                       "vswhere.exe")

# get installation path of Visual Studio 2017
vspath = subprocess.Popen([vswhere, "-property", "installationPath", "-version", "[15,16)"],
                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].rstrip()

# build path to vcvarsall.bat file
vcvarsall = os.path.join(vspath, "VC", "Auxiliary", "Build", "vcvarsall.bat")

# vcvarsall.bat changes the current directory to the one specified
# by the environment variable %VSCMD_START_DIR%
my_env = os.environ
my_env["VSCMD_START_DIR"] = build_dir

# set up the environment and then call cmake with Ninja generator
subprocess.call('call "' + vcvarsall + '" x64 && cmake -G Ninja "' + src_dir + '"', shell=True, env=my_env)
```